# Historical manhwa where the female lead was reincarnated many times and has the power to travel through space and time via her drawings

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

It's a historical manhwa where the female lead was reincarnated many times. She has the power to travel through space and time through her drawings. She tries to get revenge in her latest life.

Comment: Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead? Was she reincarnated as the same person, or as different people? Who did she try to get revenge against, and for what?